# troubles with google maps marker clustering

Tags: css, reactjs, google-maps, markerclusterer

On a React project we have a Google Maps API with interactible markers, but we failed to implement marker clustering on our project.
The imports:

```
import GoogleMap from "google-maps-react-markers";
import { MarkerClusterer } from "@react-google-maps/api";
import Marker from "./marker";
```

The Google Map API code for our project:

```
<div className="map-container" ref={mapRef}>
        <GoogleMap
          apiKey=
          defaultCenter={{ lat: 20, lng: 20 }}
          defaultZoom={14}
          onGoogleApiLoaded={onGoogleApiLoaded}
          onChange={onMapChange}
        >
          {renderedMarkers}
        </GoogleMap>
</div>
```

The code for marker:

```
const renderedMarkers = filteredMarkersByTags.map(
    (
      { lat, lng, name, variant, email, description, image, date, tag, _id },
      index
    ) => {
      if (showMyEntries && email !== profile.email) {
        return null;
      }

      return (
        <Marker
          key={index}
          lat={lat}
          lng={lng}
          markerId={name}
          variant={variant}
          markerVariant={variant}
          markerDescription={description}
          markerEmail={email}
          markerDate={date}
          petImage={image}
          markerTags={tag}
          dbID={_id}
          onClick={onMarkerClick}
          className="marker"
        />
      );
    }
  );
```

when we zoom out, the markers still remain as individuals instead of clustering for a cleaner viewing experience, thanks in advance to aynone who can help

```
<MarkerClusterer 
   averageCenter enableRetinaIcons gridSize={60}>
   { renderedMarkers }
</MarkerClusterer>
```

We made an attempt to see whether the default clustering methods work or not, so tried this segment to see whether it would cluster the markers or not. Only output we've got is a "Script error" from this attempt.

Comment: Why are you not using the `<Marker />` component from the `react-google-maps/api` library?

Comment: There seems to be an issue with the `<MarkerClusterer />` component of the library. You can follow this [Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-VJTh7OqoJI) instead if you want to continue working with marker clusterer in react.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of mentioned `@react-google-maps/api` library is not detailed enough. I found [the example](https://github.com/JustFly1984/react-google-maps-api/blob/master/packages/react-google-maps-api/src/components/addons/MarkerClusterer.md) with marker clusterer and I think the `renderedMarkers` should be a function and look the following way:

```
(clusterer) => (
  <>
    {filteredMarkersByTags.map(
    ({ lat, lng, name, variant, email, description, image, date, tag, _id }, index) => {
      if (showMyEntries && email !== profile.email) {
        return null;
      }

      return (
        <Marker
          key={index}
          lat={lat}
          lng={lng}
          clusterer={clusterer}
          position={{lat: lat, lng: lng}}
          markerId={name}
          variant={variant}
          markerVariant={variant}
          markerDescription={description}
          markerEmail={email}
          markerDate={date}
          petImage={image}
          markerTags={tag}
          dbID={_id}
          onClick={onMarkerClick}
          className="marker"
        />
      );
    }
  )}
  </>
)
```

Pay attention to two new attributes `clusterer` and `position` (in the mentioned example Marker receives the position object instead of two separate parameters `lat` and `lng`).

If it doesn't help I would suggest using the official `@googlemaps/markerclusterer` library. Here is [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering?hl=ru)